# getting error in URL why?

Tags: java

i can't understand why using such URL gives me an error

```
  httpsURL = new URL("upload1.something.com");
```

Comment: you don't have a protocol, suggest you read the spec: https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt

Comment: What tells Java that is an HTTPS URL?

Comment: Why would you omit the error in your post? Have you read the Javadoc of that `URL` constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message *tells you* the problem:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: upload1.something.com 
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:586)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:483)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:432)
    at Ideone.main(Main.java:12)
```

[<kbd>Ideone</kbd>](http://ideone.com/EeYAKS)

You are missing the protocol.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the URL javadoc :

> Throws: MalformedURLException - if no protocol is specified, or an
>   unknown protocol is found, or spec is null.

As you can see, URL's constructor expect a protocol to be specified in the URL.

Depending on your use case, you may use other data types without such constraint, such as URI.